# lua variable closure

Tags: lua, closures, anonymous-function, coronasdk

I'm new to lua and I have some problem with closures. I have a function:

```
function cell(x,y,s, group)
    local myCircle = display.newCircle( x, y, s )
    myCircle.la = 1
    local myclosure = function() 

      myCircle.la= myCirle.la + 1

    end
    timer.performWithDelay( 1500, myclosure, 0  )
    return true
end
```

But when timer callback is executed i'm getting an error:

```
   file.lua:39: attempt to index global 'myCirle' (a nil value)
```

Does function myclosure 'see' variables from function `cell` ? if not is there any way to get access to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled it. The error actually claims that you attempted to access "myCirle", not "myCircle".